# Devicemanager connected clients WCF?

Tags: wcf

I am working on a web application which acts like a Devicemanager. Clients can register with the devicemanager and connect to the devices that the manager provides.
I was thinking of using a duplex WCF service for the device connection/disconnection.
Is WCF the correct technology to use?
I will need the clients to be constantly registered to be able to connect/disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Duplex WCF service implements callback function in web services world.
With callback client sends request to server with some kind of reference to its own method that should be called by server when time came. This allows server to communicate with client when server think it is necessary.

You situation contains no need for callback implementation because process is always controlled by client:

1. Clients can register with the devicemanager
2. Clients can connect to the devices that the manager provides

So answer for Duplex is NO (if my understanding of your question is correct)

Should you use WCF – YES. 
WCF is right technology if you want to set up communication channel between two applications and TCP/IP is too low level for your needs.

Comment: The device is to be connected to the client. So when the client selects a device to be connected using the web application, the service will call a client method to connect the device to the client? The web application also needs to display the status of every device (connected/not connected). There is also a requirement for an administrator to be able to connect/disconnect any client's device.

Comment: Who controls the process when client and device are connected?